# FormProvider - TS2589: Type instantiation is excessively deep and possibly infinite

Tags: typescript

After the RN update getting "Type instantiation is excessively deep and possibly infinite":

```
<FormProvider {...methods}>
```

Environment:

```
"typescript": "^4.4.4",
"react-hook-form": "^7.19.5",
```

Answer (score 0):

This bug appears after updating "reach-hook-form" to 7.16.2+

Just downgrade the typescript version to 4.4.3

```
"typescript": "^4.4.3"
```

In 4.4.4 they added a check for TS2589.

More info about similar issue:
https://github.com/react-hook-form/react-hook-form/issues/6679

Comment: Just wanted to let others know that this solution did not work for me. Still struggling with this issue.